# PHP JOIN -> <> Results From Another Table

Tags: php, sql

Hope everyone had a good thanksgiving. I am proceeding with my project and I have joined the tables in which I need to have together in order to echo results correctly.

```
select *
from Customer 
    join Invoice
        on customer.listid = invoice.customerref_listid
    join InvoiceLineDetail
        on invoice.TxnID = invoicelinedetail.IDKEY
    join ItemInventory
        on invoicelinedetail.itemref_listid = iteminventory.listid
order by customer.name, CustomField12 asc
```

---

So now with these join results, there is two fields labeled

`CustomerFirstName CustomerLastName ItemRef_FullName` and `customfield12`. `Customfield12` is a category of product. I want to be able to pull from Table (`ItemInventory`) the products that a customer has not purchased from the categories in which they purchased from.

I am sure it is possible, but i'm lost at where to start or operators to use?

Tables (Joined) Results:

```
{
John    Doe         johndoe@aol.com Product:FrameSet1   Frame Sets
John    Doe2            johndoe2@aol.com    Product:FrameSet3   Outside Sets
}
```

Table Results (ItemInventory):

```
{
Frame Set Example 1         Product:FrameSet1           Frame Sets
Frame Set Example 2         Product:FrameSet2           Frame Sets
Frame Set Example 3         Product:FrameSet3           Outside Sets
Frame Set Example 4         Product:FrameSet4           Outside Sets
}
```

In the above example, the results would display the items in which the customer is missing that is within the same category that he/she purchased from before. There could also be more than one category that they purchased from.

Results:

```
{    
John    Doe         johndoe@aol.com Product:FrameSet2   Frame Sets
John    Doe2            johndoe2@aol.com    Product:FrameSet4   Outside Sets
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post a small sample of rows from each of the joined tables, together with a sample of what you expect the query output to be, given those exact input rows?  Edit above and paste them in as a text table, highlight and ctl-k or use the `{}` editor toolbar button to format them as a code block (which retains the tabular format)

Comment: Michael, thanks for responding so quickly. I'll do my best to see what I can do. Thanks.

Comment: Michael, the formatting didn't take correctly but I posted what you have requested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I applied code blocks (4 space indentation) to your tables. Working within that, you can adjust formatting as makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a NOT IN clause in your SQL, something like that:

```
select * from ItemInventory a , JoinedTables b
where 
a.category=b.category
and ItemID not in (Select ItemID from JoinedTables b where a.category=b.category)
```

If you gave me your table columns, I can adjust the SQL to reflect the correct select.
I assumed that your category field is called `category` and the id of your item is `ItemID`.